# Why is the selected item synchronising between multiple comboboxes bound to the same datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a question regarding the use of databinding and multiple comboboxes.

I have a manager class that handles the data I want to bind. It looks like this:

```
public static class SupplierManager
{
    private static List<Classes.Supplier> _suppliers = null;
    private static BindingSource _bindingSource = null;

    public static void Add(Classes.Supplier supplier)
    {
        if (_suppliers == null)
        {
            _suppliers = new List<Classes.Supplier>();
            _suppliers.Add(new Classes.Supplier());
        }

        if (_bindingSource == null)
        {
            _bindingSource = new BindingSource(_suppliers, null);
        }

        _bindingSource.Add(supplier);
        _suppliers.Sort();
    }

    public static void Remove(Classes.Supplier supplier)
    {
        _bindingSource.Remove(supplier);
        _suppliers.Sort();
    }

    public static BindingSource BindingSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (_suppliers == null)
            {
                _suppliers = new List<Classes.Supplier>();
                _suppliers.Add(new Classes.Supplier());
            }

            if (_bindingSource == null)
            {
                _bindingSource = new BindingSource(_suppliers, null);
            }

            return _bindingSource;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this (all input is welcome!) but it does the trick for me BUT my issue is that when I have 2 or more comboboxes connected to the same  BindingSource they are in sync so that when I select an item in combobox1 it also gets selected in combobox2.

What I want is that the comboboxes have the same data in them and that they get updated if the BindingSource changes without any need to refresh the specific combobox (which it does) but that the selected item should not be in sync.

I set the datasource to the comboboxes like this:

```
public ReceiptOUT()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.cmbBxSuppliers.DataSource = Managers.SupplierManager.BindingSource;
        this.cmbBxSuppliers.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        this.cmbBxSuppliers.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

All help (even if it's not related to this question but also on the rest of the code) is welcome!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I will as soon as I am able to... I have to wait 8 hours (2 hours left) first apperently ;) I have to make sure I'm a bit more active on here so my rep goes up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this... so easy I must have been blind ;)

```
public static BindingSource BindingSource
{
    get
    {
        if (_suppliers == null)
        {
            _suppliers = new BindingList<Classes.Supplier>();
        }

        return new BindingSource(_suppliers, null);
    }
}
```

And changed the `List<Classes.Supplier> _suppliers` to `BindingList<Classes.Supplier> _suppliers`